# Error from server (BadRequest): pod kubia-zgxn9 does not have a host assigned

Tags: kubernetes

When I run exec command

```
 kubectl exec kubia-zgxn9 -- curl -s http://10.47.252.17
Error from server (BadRequest): pod kubia-zgxn9 does not have a host assigned
```

Describe pod shows host

```
IP:             
Controlled By:  ReplicationController/kubia
Containers:
  kubia:
    Image:      luksa/kubia
    Port:       8080/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-xs7qx (ro)
```

This is my service

```
Name:              kubia
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=kubia
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.47.252.17
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Why did I get error from server?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Pod is probably not yet scheduled to a Node.

Maybe it just took a little longer than expected or perhaps it's asking for resources that no node can satisfy at the moment.

Check the output of `kubectl get pod kubia-zgxn9` and see if the state is `Running`. If so, retry now. If it still fails to exec this might be a bug.

If it's not running, check the describe output for notices. (Unfortunately you cut the output short in your question so we can't see what's wrong with it).

Comment: No,status is Pending.

Comment: If you have trouble finding out why it's pending post another question with the output of `kubectl describe pod kubia-zgxn9`

Answer (score 1):

like [Janos Lenart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50831348/23490365) said, The Pod is probably not yet scheduled to a Node, maybe because of resources (in my case was cpu). I think this may help :  [pending pod on minikube kubernetes : insufficient cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61795050/pending-pod-on-minikube-kubernetes-insufficient-cpu)