# pending pod on minikube kubernetes : insufficient cpu

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Running an application with `three services` on my local `minikube` while was installed on a server with **16 cpus and 64 GB of memory** , one `replicas` of which is 2, I only set resources.limits for each service, as shown below

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: "2"
    memory: "209715200"
```

> All service resource restrictions are the same.

However, some service `pending` appears.

The pending Pod describe partial output is as follows

```
Limits:
  cpu:     2
  memory:  209715200
Requests:
  cpu:     2
  memory:  209715200
...

Events:
  Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
  ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu.
```

> The result of `kubectl get pod` is as follows

```
kubectl get pod
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
test1-777f54bcdb-pvfn5      1/1     Running   0          4m49s
test2-75ccb875b-lj9xl       1/1     Running   0          4m48s
test2-75ccb875b-s7xht       1/1     Running   0          4m48s
test3-797f6b795f-z9qv5      0/1     Pending   0          4m48s
```

> The result of `kubectl top node` is as follows

```
kubectl top node
NAME CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
test   1057m        13%    31675Mi         50%
```

> minikube version

```
# minikube version
minikube version: v1.9.2
commit: 93af9c1e43cab9618e301bc9fa720c63d5efa393
```

> kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:27:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I'm confused that my server configuration should be able to run this application, but it pend due to **insufficient CPU**

Any comments would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: If you `kubectl describe node test` it will tell you what pods (including system pods) are scheduled there and how much capacity it has.  Scheduling is based on resource requests so even if you have low actual CPU utilization, since each pod requests 2 full cores, that limits what can be placed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running minikube with stock configs isn't going to make use of all your hardware potential. Minikube allows you to create nodes as big as you need and this is very important because the majority of people are using minikube on their workstation besides other applications and they don't want minikube to have unrestricted access to use your hardware.

To start minikube with custom specs you can do as [Radek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61795256/12153576) described, where you specify the amount of cpus and memory while starting your minikube.

```
$ minikube start --cpus N --memory N
```

Another option is to set these parameters as default:

```
$ minikube config set cpus N
$ minikube config set memory N
```

To check all configurable parameters you can run `minikube config`.

Another reason to have your nodes with limited resources is that you can have a minikube cluster with multiple nodes and also multiple clusters on one machine.
To create a minikube cluster with multiple nodes you can run:

```
$ minikube start -n X
```

Where X is the number of desired nodes.

If you have a running minikube cluster and want to add another node to it, you can run:

```
$ minikube node add
```

To create a secondary minikube cluster you can run:

```
$ minikube start -p cluster-name
```

Where cluster-name is a name of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you run minikube in a VM it is restricted by the amount of VM CPUs not the host ones. You can use `minikube start --cpus N` to start with N vCPUs

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, this is my situation:

I am using minikube with 1cpu `minikube start --driver=docker --extra-config=kubeadm.ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU --force --cpus 1`

I was playing with ingress addon in minikube, I enable it for testing it:

```
minikube addons list
minikube addons enable ingress
```

and after a while of testing ingress, I tried to install Influxdb (using Helm), but I faced that problem :
`Warning  FailedScheduling  56s   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..`

so I disabled ingress addon `minikube addons disable ingress` and when I tried again influxdb, it works, the error gone.

the output of `minikube addons list` in my case :

| ADDON NAME | PROFILE | STATUS | MAINTAINER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ambassador | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Ambassador) |
| auto-pause | minikube | disabled | minikube |
| cloud-spanner | minikube | disabled | Google |
| csi-hostpath-driver | minikube | disabled | Kubernetes |
| dashboard | minikube | enabled ✅ | Kubernetes |
| default-storageclass | minikube | enabled ✅ | Kubernetes |
| efk | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Elastic) |
| freshpod | minikube | disabled | Google |
| gcp-auth | minikube | disabled | Google |
| gvisor | minikube | disabled | minikube |
| headlamp | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (kinvolk.io) |
| helm-tiller | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Helm) |
| inaccel | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (InAccel |
|  |  |  | [info@inaccel.com]) |
| ingress | minikube | disabled | Kubernetes |
| ingress-dns | minikube | disabled | minikube |
| inspektor-gadget | minikube | disabled | 3rd party |
|  |  |  | (inspektor-gadget.io) |
| istio | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Istio) |
| istio-provisioner | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Istio) |
| kong | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Kong HQ) |
| kubeflow | minikube | disabled | 3rd party |
| kubevirt | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (KubeVirt) |
| logviewer | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (unknown) |
| metallb | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (MetalLB) |
| metrics-server | minikube | enabled ✅ | Kubernetes |
| nvidia-device-plugin | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (NVIDIA) |
| nvidia-driver-installer | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Nvidia) |
| nvidia-gpu-device-plugin | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Nvidia) |
| olm | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Operator Framework) |
| pod-security-policy | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (unknown) |
| portainer | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Portainer.io) |
| registry | minikube | disabled | minikube |
| registry-aliases | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (unknown) |
| registry-creds | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (UPMC Enterprises) |
| storage-provisioner | minikube | enabled ✅ | minikube |
| storage-provisioner-gluster | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Gluster) |
| storage-provisioner-rancher | minikube | disabled | 3rd party (Rancher) |
| volumesnapshots | minikube | disabled | Kubernetes |

So, I think the problem in my case was because I run a lot of pods (because enabling ingress addon, it create more pods).